# How to configure PhpStorm to resolve Global NPM modules?

Tags: javascript, npm, phpstorm, node-modules, phpstorm-2017.1

I am developing WordPress plugin, so my directory path of interest is:
`wp-content/plugins/pg-assets-portfolio/package.json`

I have `NodeJS` and `JavaScript support` plugins installed (Version: 171.4694.2 and Version: 1.0).

In a specific file where I use Browserify's API (installed globally into `/usr/lib/node_modules`) to convert NPM modules. There I have `require('browserify');` underlined. PhpStorm says "Module is not installed"

[image]

I also have defined in my `.profile` file:

```
export NODE_PATH=/usr/lib/node_modules
```

Here is my "Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > Libraries" config:

[image]

And here is Node.js and NPM

[image]

And Usage Scopes:

[image]

How to properly configure PhpStorm to make it recognize of global package?

Answer (score 0):

Alt+Enter on underlined module > Install. Check if it's added to dependencies in package.json

Comment: browserify is installed globally (`npm install -g`)